Could you help me make my Hard Disk my default saving path instead of the current NVME SSD?
SSD: 256 GB Hard Disk: 1.0 TB
These are what partitions on my computer look like:
sda           8:0    0 931.5G  0 disk
  ├─sda1        8:1    0   579M  0 part
  ├─sda2        8:2    0  97.1G  0 part
  ├─sda3        8:3    0 394.4G  0 part /media/afzia/7fe5b65e-bb1e-4262-aa86-831a700fb3dd
  └─sda4        8:4    0 439.5G  0 part /media/afzia/16828FCB828FAE35
nvme0n1     259:0    0 238.5G  0 disk
  ├─nvme0n1p1 259:1    0   100M  0 part /boot/efi
  ├─nvme0n1p2 259:2    0    16M  0 part
  ├─nvme0n1p3 259:3    0 121.3G  0 part
  ├─nvme0n1p4 259:4    0   674M  0 part 
  ├─nvme0n1p5 259:5    0  22.9G  0 part
  ├─nvme0n1p6 259:6    0  56.5G  0 part
  └─nvme0n1p7 259:7    0    37G  0 part /var/snap/firefox/common/host-hunspell/

location where I want my file to be saved:
/dev/sda3: UUID="7fe5b65e-bb1e-4262-aa86-831a700fb3dd" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="79817ab4-03"

instead of this:
/dev/nvme0n1p5: LABEL="UBUNTU NVME" BLOCK_SIZE="512" UUID="AA12B98012B95255" TYPE="ntfs" PARTLABEL="Basic data partition" PARTUUID="fcb75ae6-c50b-4031-b16f-4c33d9d634ca"

I need step-by-step guidance on how to set the default saving location for my hard disk. P.S.: I have tried to change the directory using
*nano ~/.config/user-dirs.dirs

but that didn't work!
I tried using
nano ~/.config/user-dirs.dirs

to overwrite internal code to
XDG_DESKTOP_DIR="/media/afzia/7fe5b65e-bb1e-4262-aa86-831a700fb3dd/Desktop" XDG_DOWNLOAD_DIR="/media/afzia/7fe5b65e-bb1e-4262-aa86-831a700fb3dd/Downloads" XDG_DOCUMENTS_DIR="/media/afzia/7fe5b65e-bb1e-4262-aa86-831a700fb3dd/Documents" XDG_MUSIC_DIR="/media/afzia/7fe5b65e-bb1e-4262-aa86-831a700fb3dd/Music" XDG_PICTURES_DIR="/media/afzia/7fe5b65e-bb1e-4262-aa86-831a700fb3dd/Pictures" XDG_VIDEOS_DIR="/media/afzia/7fe5b65e-bb1e-4262-aa86-831a700fb3dd/Videos"

saved and exited the file,
then opened this file,
sudo nano /etc/fstab

added this line to this file:
UUID=7fe5b65e-bb1e-4262-aa86-831a700fb3dd /media/afzia/7fe5b65e-bb1e-4262-aa86-831a700fb3dd ext4 defaults 0 2

saved and exited the code but after rebooting nothing changed. Could you help me out with solving this?
P.S.: The hard disk space had read, write, and execute permissions and is mounted to my NVME Ubuntu partition on SSD.

You want so only in Firefox?

"Default saving path", but for which application?
There is no general "default saving path" in Ubuntu.

I keep /home inside / (root), but have all data in a separate data partition. Mount in fstab, set ownership & permissions & ownership. I think link folders back into /home. Details: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1013677/storing-data-on-second-hdd-mounting &
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1058756/installing-all-applications-on-a-ssd-disk-and-putting-all-files-on-hdd-disk & https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2488332&p=14149243#post14149243 While I do all folders, you can do just those your want to link.

If you want your ALL your personal files to end up on /dev/sda3 then your best option is to "move /home" to that disk.
How to, askubuntu:
Move home folder to second drive

The OP clearly said that /dev/nvme0n1p5 is NOT the location he wants.

So, I copied the wrong string, bugger
